# iptables configuration for squid proxy in bridged mode

Tags: squid, bridge

I recently set up a squid proxy in bridged mode. But Squid is not caching due to some firewall issues I guess. Manual caching is perfectly ok.
Here is what I have set up in **/etc/rc.local**

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0 promisc up
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1
ifconfig br0 192.168.1.30 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.1.1 dev br0
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --ip-protocol 6 --ip-destination-port 80 -j redirect --redirect-target ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Squid is configured on port **8080 in transparent mode**.

What could be the issue?

Comment: `But Squid is not caching due to some firewall issues I guess.` - Do you mean that http requests are not being intercepted and handled by squid, or do you mean squid is literally not using the cache for the requests.

Comment: Also, do you see the traffic you are expecting to be intercepted when when you run tcpdump on the bridge interface?

Comment: Yes issuing TCP dump shows traffic from bridged network. But the traffic is not being intercepted by squid cache.

Comment: Experiencing what is probably the same issue myself. Works well in testing where I plug my laptop directly to one of the eth interfaces (router is connected to the other Interface) but not when a switch using VLANs is used instead of a single device. tcpdump shows traffic, but as long as ebtables and iptables rules are enabled the clients cannot browse (other ports' traffic are unaffected)